# Empty plot with gnuplot and lualatex but not with pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot with its tikz terminal to make a `.tex` file that can be compiled to generate a plot. The `.tex` file is okey since it can be compiled with `pdflatex` and produces the plot I made. However, plotting with `lualatex` yields a plot with axis and labels but empty (see MWE I provided).
The problem seems to be `lualatex`. I suspect that it has to do with the new version of lualatex because at home this works fine with Ubuntu's version of TeX Live (2015 I think) and in this PC the 2016 version is installed (from a few weeks ago and the official web page, everything should be up to date).

Here, I have a minimal working example. Gnuplot file:

```
set term tikz standalone createstyle
set output 'test.tex'

plot 'data.txt' u 1:2:3 w image not
```

data file (data.txt):

```
1 1 1
1 2 2
2 1 3
2 2 4
```

Output with pdflatex:
[image]

Output with lualatex:
[image]

Including the package `luatex85` does not help for this particular plot. This is the `.tex` file that gnuplot generates, for reference:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{\gpbboxborder}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
%% generated with GNUPLOT 5.0p5 (Lua 5.1; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
%% Thu 20 Apr 2017 19:40:07 CEST
\path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (12.500,8.750);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetdashtype{gp dt solid}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.012,0.616)--(1.192,0.616);
\draw[gp path] (10.283,0.616)--(10.103,0.616);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,0.616) {$0.5$};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,2.557)--(1.192,2.557);
\draw[gp path] (10.283,2.557)--(10.103,2.557);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,2.557) {$1$};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,4.499)--(1.192,4.499);
\draw[gp path] (10.283,4.499)--(10.103,4.499);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,4.499) {$1.5$};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,6.440)--(1.192,6.440);
\draw[gp path] (10.283,6.440)--(10.103,6.440);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,6.440) {$2$};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.192,8.381);
\draw[gp path] (10.283,8.381)--(10.103,8.381);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,8.381) {$2.5$};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,0.616)--(1.012,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (1.012,0.308) {$0.5$};
\draw[gp path] (3.330,0.616)--(3.330,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (3.330,8.381)--(3.330,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (3.330,0.308) {$1$};
\draw[gp path] (5.648,0.616)--(5.648,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (5.648,8.381)--(5.648,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (5.648,0.308) {$1.5$};
\draw[gp path] (7.965,0.616)--(7.965,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (7.965,8.381)--(7.965,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (7.965,0.308) {$2$};
\draw[gp path] (10.283,0.616)--(10.283,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (10.283,8.381)--(10.283,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (10.283,0.308) {$2.5$};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,0.616)--(10.283,0.616)--(10.283,8.381)--cycle;
\begin{scope}
\clip (1.012,8.381) rectangle (10.283,0.616);
\def\gprawrgbimagedata{%
  9309ddffff00000000d04c00}%
\gprawimage{rgb}{1.012}{0.616}{2}{2}{9.271}{7.765}{\gprawrgbimagedata}{}
\end{scope}
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,0.616)--(10.283,0.616)--(10.283,8.381)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.011,0.000,0.001}} (10.515,0.616)--(10.978,0.616)--(10.978,0.677)--(10.515,0.677)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.089,0.000,0.049}} (10.515,0.676)--(10.978,0.676)--(10.978,0.738)--(10.515,0.738)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.125,0.000,0.099}} (10.515,0.737)--(10.978,0.737)--(10.978,0.798)--(10.515,0.798)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.153,0.000,0.147}} (10.515,0.797)--(10.978,0.797)--(10.978,0.859)--(10.515,0.859)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.177,0.000,0.195}} (10.515,0.858)--(10.978,0.858)--(10.978,0.920)--(10.515,0.920)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.198,0.000,0.244}} (10.515,0.919)--(10.978,0.919)--(10.978,0.980)--(10.515,0.980)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.217,0.000,0.290}} (10.515,0.979)--(10.978,0.979)--(10.978,1.041)--(10.515,1.041)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.234,0.000,0.337}} (10.515,1.040)--(10.978,1.040)--(10.978,1.102)--(10.515,1.102)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.250,0.000,0.383}} (10.515,1.101)--(10.978,1.101)--(10.978,1.162)--(10.515,1.162)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.265,0.000,0.428}} (10.515,1.161)--(10.978,1.161)--(10.978,1.223)--(10.515,1.223)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.280,0.000,0.472}} (10.515,1.222)--(10.978,1.222)--(10.978,1.284)--(10.515,1.284)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.293,0.001,0.515}} (10.515,1.283)--(10.978,1.283)--(10.978,1.344)--(10.515,1.344)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.306,0.001,0.556}} (10.515,1.343)--(10.978,1.343)--(10.978,1.405)--(10.515,1.405)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.319,0.001,0.596}} (10.515,1.404)--(10.978,1.404)--(10.978,1.466)--(10.515,1.466)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.331,0.001,0.635}} (10.515,1.465)--(10.978,1.465)--(10.978,1.526)--(10.515,1.526)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.342,0.002,0.672}} (10.515,1.525)--(10.978,1.525)--(10.978,1.587)--(10.515,1.587)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.354,0.002,0.707}} (10.515,1.586)--(10.978,1.586)--(10.978,1.648)--(10.515,1.648)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.365,0.002,0.741}} (10.515,1.647)--(10.978,1.647)--(10.978,1.708)--(10.515,1.708)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.375,0.003,0.773}} (10.515,1.707)--(10.978,1.707)--(10.978,1.769)--(10.515,1.769)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.385,0.003,0.803}} (10.515,1.768)--(10.978,1.768)--(10.978,1.830)--(10.515,1.830)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.395,0.004,0.832}} (10.515,1.829)--(10.978,1.829)--(10.978,1.890)--(10.515,1.890)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.405,0.004,0.858}} (10.515,1.889)--(10.978,1.889)--(10.978,1.951)--(10.515,1.951)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.415,0.005,0.882}} (10.515,1.950)--(10.978,1.950)--(10.978,2.012)--(10.515,2.012)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.424,0.006,0.904}} (10.515,2.011)--(10.978,2.011)--(10.978,2.072)--(10.515,2.072)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.433,0.007,0.924}} (10.515,2.071)--(10.978,2.071)--(10.978,2.133)--(10.515,2.133)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.442,0.007,0.942}} (10.515,2.132)--(10.978,2.132)--(10.978,2.194)--(10.515,2.194)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.451,0.008,0.957}} (10.515,2.193)--(10.978,2.193)--(10.978,2.254)--(10.515,2.254)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.459,0.009,0.970}} (10.515,2.253)--(10.978,2.253)--(10.978,2.315)--(10.515,2.315)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.468,0.010,0.981}} (10.515,2.314)--(10.978,2.314)--(10.978,2.376)--(10.515,2.376)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.476,0.012,0.989}} (10.515,2.375)--(10.978,2.375)--(10.978,2.436)--(10.515,2.436)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.484,0.013,0.995}} (10.515,2.435)--(10.978,2.435)--(10.978,2.497)--(10.515,2.497)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.492,0.014,0.999}} (10.515,2.496)--(10.978,2.496)--(10.978,2.558)--(10.515,2.558)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.500,0.016,1.000}} (10.515,2.557)--(10.978,2.557)--(10.978,2.618)--(10.515,2.618)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.508,0.017,0.999}} (10.515,2.617)--(10.978,2.617)--(10.978,2.679)--(10.515,2.679)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.515,0.019,0.995}} (10.515,2.678)--(10.978,2.678)--(10.978,2.740)--(10.515,2.740)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.523,0.020,0.989}} (10.515,2.739)--(10.978,2.739)--(10.978,2.800)--(10.515,2.800)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.530,0.022,0.981}} (10.515,2.799)--(10.978,2.799)--(10.978,2.861)--(10.515,2.861)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.538,0.024,0.970}} (10.515,2.860)--(10.978,2.860)--(10.978,2.922)--(10.515,2.922)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.545,0.026,0.957}} (10.515,2.921)--(10.978,2.921)--(10.978,2.982)--(10.515,2.982)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.552,0.028,0.942}} (10.515,2.981)--(10.978,2.981)--(10.978,3.043)--(10.515,3.043)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.559,0.031,0.924}} (10.515,3.042)--(10.978,3.042)--(10.978,3.104)--(10.515,3.104)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.566,0.033,0.904}} (10.515,3.103)--(10.978,3.103)--(10.978,3.164)--(10.515,3.164)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.573,0.035,0.882}} (10.515,3.163)--(10.978,3.163)--(10.978,3.225)--(10.515,3.225)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.580,0.038,0.858}} (10.515,3.224)--(10.978,3.224)--(10.978,3.286)--(10.515,3.286)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.586,0.041,0.831}} (10.515,3.285)--(10.978,3.285)--(10.978,3.346)--(10.515,3.346)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.593,0.043,0.803}} (10.515,3.345)--(10.978,3.345)--(10.978,3.407)--(10.515,3.407)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.600,0.046,0.773}} (10.515,3.406)--(10.978,3.406)--(10.978,3.468)--(10.515,3.468)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.606,0.050,0.741}} (10.515,3.467)--(10.978,3.467)--(10.978,3.528)--(10.515,3.528)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.612,0.053,0.707}} (10.515,3.527)--(10.978,3.527)--(10.978,3.589)--(10.515,3.589)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.619,0.056,0.671}} (10.515,3.588)--(10.978,3.588)--(10.978,3.650)--(10.515,3.650)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.625,0.060,0.634}} (10.515,3.649)--(10.978,3.649)--(10.978,3.710)--(10.515,3.710)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.631,0.063,0.596}} (10.515,3.709)--(10.978,3.709)--(10.978,3.771)--(10.515,3.771)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.637,0.067,0.555}} (10.515,3.770)--(10.978,3.770)--(10.978,3.832)--(10.515,3.832)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.644,0.071,0.514}} (10.515,3.831)--(10.978,3.831)--(10.978,3.892)--(10.515,3.892)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.650,0.075,0.471}} (10.515,3.891)--(10.978,3.891)--(10.978,3.953)--(10.515,3.953)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.656,0.079,0.427}} (10.515,3.952)--(10.978,3.952)--(10.978,4.014)--(10.515,4.014)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.662,0.084,0.382}} (10.515,4.013)--(10.978,4.013)--(10.978,4.074)--(10.515,4.074)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.667,0.088,0.337}} (10.515,4.073)--(10.978,4.073)--(10.978,4.135)--(10.515,4.135)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.673,0.093,0.290}} (10.515,4.134)--(10.978,4.134)--(10.978,4.196)--(10.515,4.196)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.679,0.098,0.242}} (10.515,4.195)--(10.978,4.195)--(10.978,4.256)--(10.515,4.256)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.685,0.103,0.195}} (10.515,4.255)--(10.978,4.255)--(10.978,4.317)--(10.515,4.317)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.690,0.108,0.146}} (10.515,4.316)--(10.978,4.316)--(10.978,4.378)--(10.515,4.378)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.696,0.114,0.097}} (10.515,4.377)--(10.978,4.377)--(10.978,4.438)--(10.515,4.438)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.702,0.119,0.049}} (10.515,4.437)--(10.978,4.437)--(10.978,4.499)--(10.515,4.499)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.707,0.125,0.000}} (10.515,4.498)--(10.978,4.498)--(10.978,4.560)--(10.515,4.560)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.713,0.131,0.000}} (10.515,4.559)--(10.978,4.559)--(10.978,4.620)--(10.515,4.620)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.718,0.137,0.000}} (10.515,4.619)--(10.978,4.619)--(10.978,4.681)--(10.515,4.681)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.724,0.143,0.000}} (10.515,4.680)--(10.978,4.680)--(10.978,4.742)--(10.515,4.742)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.729,0.150,0.000}} (10.515,4.741)--(10.978,4.741)--(10.978,4.802)--(10.515,4.802)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.734,0.157,0.000}} (10.515,4.801)--(10.978,4.801)--(10.978,4.863)--(10.515,4.863)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.740,0.164,0.000}} (10.515,4.862)--(10.978,4.862)--(10.978,4.924)--(10.515,4.924)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.745,0.171,0.000}} (10.515,4.923)--(10.978,4.923)--(10.978,4.984)--(10.515,4.984)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.750,0.178,0.000}} (10.515,4.983)--(10.978,4.983)--(10.978,5.045)--(10.515,5.045)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.755,0.186,0.000}} (10.515,5.044)--(10.978,5.044)--(10.978,5.106)--(10.515,5.106)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.760,0.193,0.000}} (10.515,5.105)--(10.978,5.105)--(10.978,5.166)--(10.515,5.166)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.765,0.201,0.000}} (10.515,5.165)--(10.978,5.165)--(10.978,5.227)--(10.515,5.227)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.771,0.209,0.000}} (10.515,5.226)--(10.978,5.226)--(10.978,5.288)--(10.515,5.288)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.776,0.218,0.000}} (10.515,5.287)--(10.978,5.287)--(10.978,5.348)--(10.515,5.348)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.781,0.226,0.000}} (10.515,5.347)--(10.978,5.347)--(10.978,5.409)--(10.515,5.409)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.786,0.235,0.000}} (10.515,5.408)--(10.978,5.408)--(10.978,5.470)--(10.515,5.470)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.791,0.244,0.000}} (10.515,5.469)--(10.978,5.469)--(10.978,5.530)--(10.515,5.530)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.796,0.253,0.000}} (10.515,5.529)--(10.978,5.529)--(10.978,5.591)--(10.515,5.591)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.800,0.263,0.000}} (10.515,5.590)--(10.978,5.590)--(10.978,5.652)--(10.515,5.652)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.805,0.273,0.000}} (10.515,5.651)--(10.978,5.651)--(10.978,5.712)--(10.515,5.712)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.810,0.283,0.000}} (10.515,5.711)--(10.978,5.711)--(10.978,5.773)--(10.515,5.773)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.815,0.293,0.000}} (10.515,5.772)--(10.978,5.772)--(10.978,5.834)--(10.515,5.834)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.820,0.303,0.000}} (10.515,5.833)--(10.978,5.833)--(10.978,5.894)--(10.515,5.894)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.824,0.314,0.000}} (10.515,5.893)--(10.978,5.893)--(10.978,5.955)--(10.515,5.955)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.829,0.325,0.000}} (10.515,5.954)--(10.978,5.954)--(10.978,6.016)--(10.515,6.016)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.834,0.336,0.000}} (10.515,6.015)--(10.978,6.015)--(10.978,6.076)--(10.515,6.076)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.839,0.348,0.000}} (10.515,6.075)--(10.978,6.075)--(10.978,6.137)--(10.515,6.137)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.843,0.359,0.000}} (10.515,6.136)--(10.978,6.136)--(10.978,6.198)--(10.515,6.198)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.848,0.371,0.000}} (10.515,6.197)--(10.978,6.197)--(10.978,6.258)--(10.515,6.258)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.852,0.384,0.000}} (10.515,6.257)--(10.978,6.257)--(10.978,6.319)--(10.515,6.319)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.857,0.396,0.000}} (10.515,6.318)--(10.978,6.318)--(10.978,6.380)--(10.515,6.380)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.862,0.409,0.000}} (10.515,6.379)--(10.978,6.379)--(10.978,6.440)--(10.515,6.440)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.866,0.422,0.000}} (10.515,6.439)--(10.978,6.439)--(10.978,6.501)--(10.515,6.501)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.871,0.435,0.000}} (10.515,6.500)--(10.978,6.500)--(10.978,6.562)--(10.515,6.562)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.875,0.449,0.000}} (10.515,6.561)--(10.978,6.561)--(10.978,6.622)--(10.515,6.622)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.879,0.463,0.000}} (10.515,6.621)--(10.978,6.621)--(10.978,6.683)--(10.515,6.683)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.884,0.477,0.000}} (10.515,6.682)--(10.978,6.682)--(10.978,6.744)--(10.515,6.744)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.888,0.492,0.000}} (10.515,6.743)--(10.978,6.743)--(10.978,6.804)--(10.515,6.804)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.893,0.506,0.000}} (10.515,6.803)--(10.978,6.803)--(10.978,6.865)--(10.515,6.865)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.897,0.521,0.000}} (10.515,6.864)--(10.978,6.864)--(10.978,6.926)--(10.515,6.926)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.901,0.537,0.000}} (10.515,6.925)--(10.978,6.925)--(10.978,6.986)--(10.515,6.986)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.906,0.552,0.000}} (10.515,6.985)--(10.978,6.985)--(10.978,7.047)--(10.515,7.047)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.910,0.568,0.000}} (10.515,7.046)--(10.978,7.046)--(10.978,7.108)--(10.515,7.108)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.914,0.584,0.000}} (10.515,7.107)--(10.978,7.107)--(10.978,7.168)--(10.515,7.168)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.919,0.601,0.000}} (10.515,7.167)--(10.978,7.167)--(10.978,7.229)--(10.515,7.229)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.923,0.618,0.000}} (10.515,7.228)--(10.978,7.228)--(10.978,7.290)--(10.515,7.290)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.927,0.635,0.000}} (10.515,7.289)--(10.978,7.289)--(10.978,7.350)--(10.515,7.350)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.931,0.652,0.000}} (10.515,7.349)--(10.978,7.349)--(10.978,7.411)--(10.515,7.411)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.935,0.670,0.000}} (10.515,7.410)--(10.978,7.410)--(10.978,7.472)--(10.515,7.472)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.940,0.688,0.000}} (10.515,7.471)--(10.978,7.471)--(10.978,7.532)--(10.515,7.532)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.944,0.707,0.000}} (10.515,7.531)--(10.978,7.531)--(10.978,7.593)--(10.515,7.593)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.948,0.725,0.000}} (10.515,7.592)--(10.978,7.592)--(10.978,7.654)--(10.515,7.654)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.952,0.745,0.000}} (10.515,7.653)--(10.978,7.653)--(10.978,7.714)--(10.515,7.714)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.956,0.764,0.000}} (10.515,7.713)--(10.978,7.713)--(10.978,7.775)--(10.515,7.775)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.960,0.784,0.000}} (10.515,7.774)--(10.978,7.774)--(10.978,7.836)--(10.515,7.836)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.964,0.804,0.000}} (10.515,7.835)--(10.978,7.835)--(10.978,7.896)--(10.515,7.896)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.968,0.824,0.000}} (10.515,7.895)--(10.978,7.895)--(10.978,7.957)--(10.515,7.957)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.972,0.845,0.000}} (10.515,7.956)--(10.978,7.956)--(10.978,8.018)--(10.515,8.018)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.976,0.866,0.000}} (10.515,8.017)--(10.978,8.017)--(10.978,8.078)--(10.515,8.078)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.980,0.887,0.000}} (10.515,8.077)--(10.978,8.077)--(10.978,8.139)--(10.515,8.139)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.984,0.909,0.000}} (10.515,8.138)--(10.978,8.138)--(10.978,8.200)--(10.515,8.200)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.988,0.932,0.000}} (10.515,8.199)--(10.978,8.199)--(10.978,8.260)--(10.515,8.260)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.992,0.954,0.000}} (10.515,8.259)--(10.978,8.259)--(10.978,8.321)--(10.515,8.321)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.996,0.977,0.000}} (10.515,8.320)--(10.978,8.320)--(10.978,8.381)--(10.515,8.381)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (10.515,0.616)--(10.978,0.616)--(10.978,8.381)--(10.515,8.381)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (10.978,0.616)--(10.798,0.616);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,0.616) {$1$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,0.616)--(10.695,0.616);
\draw[gp path] (10.978,1.910)--(10.798,1.910);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,1.910) {$1.5$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,1.910)--(10.695,1.910);
\draw[gp path] (10.978,3.204)--(10.798,3.204);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,3.204) {$2$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,3.204)--(10.695,3.204);
\draw[gp path] (10.978,4.498)--(10.798,4.498);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,4.498) {$2.5$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,4.498)--(10.695,4.498);
\draw[gp path] (10.978,5.792)--(10.798,5.792);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,5.792) {$3$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,5.792)--(10.695,5.792);
\draw[gp path] (10.978,7.086)--(10.798,7.086);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,7.086) {$3.5$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,7.086)--(10.695,7.086);
\draw[gp path] (10.978,8.381)--(10.798,8.381);
\node[gp node left] at (11.162,8.381) {$4$};
\draw[gp path] (10.515,8.381)--(10.695,8.381);
%% coordinates of the plot area
\gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{1.012cm}{0.616cm}}{\pgfpoint{10.283cm}{8.381cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
%% gnuplot variables
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on what is wrong? Does `lualatex` handle `tikz` commands differently from `pdflatex`?

Comment: my first suspect would be the preview package. But without the gnuplot-sty I can't test.

Comment: I removed the use of preview and the two following lines and it is still empty. Maybe I can include the sty files but there are a few more files included in the sty; I guess I can include them all if you want.

Comment: You can use some upload service for larger files.

Comment: I can reproduce. Diagnosis and workaround below. Please report this to the `gnuplot` developer(s). Tell them there are better, standard ways to determine if they are outputting PDF, PS or whatever, and that irregular pentagonal wheels are poor sellers for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

1. `preview` + LuaTeX -> :( ;
2. probably irrelevant here, `inputenc` + `utf8x` + `fontenc` + `textcomp` + unicode engine -> not an altogether promising combination;
3. `gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex` is dumb.

The code is dumb on at least two counts.

1. It tries to reinvent the wheel in a kind of irregular pentagon shape, rather than using the readily available off-the-peg round kind trusted by discerning users for years. A comment in the source indicates the author doesn't think much of the irregular pentagonal design, but apparently didn't bother to investigate other options.
2. It is oblivious to the existence of LuaTeX. Since it defaults to an HTML fall-back if neither PDF nor PS is deemed appropriate, it tries to use the HTML. As far as it is concerned, you are not producing either PS or PDF. This is why you get all those warnings about 'Non-PDF specials' being ignored. That's your plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
% do not load inputenc with unicode engines, especially not whith utf8x which makes no sense
% in general, unless you really know what you're doing, don't load fontenc or textcomp either

\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

% the preview package does not get along with luatex

\makeatletter
% gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex is (1) dumb and (2) oblivious to the existence of luatex
\def\gp@rawimage{\gp@rawimage@pdf}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
  %% generated with GNUPLOT 5.0p5 (Lua 5.1; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
  %% Thu 20 Apr 2017 19:40:07 CEST
  \path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (12.500,8.750);
  \gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
  \gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
  \gpsetdashtype{gp dt solid}
  \gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,0.616)--(1.192,0.616);
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,0.616)--(10.103,0.616);
  \node[gp node right] at (0.828,0.616) {$0.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,2.557)--(1.192,2.557);
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,2.557)--(10.103,2.557);
  \node[gp node right] at (0.828,2.557) {$1$};
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,4.499)--(1.192,4.499);
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,4.499)--(10.103,4.499);
  \node[gp node right] at (0.828,4.499) {$1.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,6.440)--(1.192,6.440);
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,6.440)--(10.103,6.440);
  \node[gp node right] at (0.828,6.440) {$2$};
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.192,8.381);
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,8.381)--(10.103,8.381);
  \node[gp node right] at (0.828,8.381) {$2.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,0.616)--(1.012,0.796);
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,8.201);
  \node[gp node center] at (1.012,0.308) {$0.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (3.330,0.616)--(3.330,0.796);
  \draw[gp path] (3.330,8.381)--(3.330,8.201);
  \node[gp node center] at (3.330,0.308) {$1$};
  \draw[gp path] (5.648,0.616)--(5.648,0.796);
  \draw[gp path] (5.648,8.381)--(5.648,8.201);
  \node[gp node center] at (5.648,0.308) {$1.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (7.965,0.616)--(7.965,0.796);
  \draw[gp path] (7.965,8.381)--(7.965,8.201);
  \node[gp node center] at (7.965,0.308) {$2$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,0.616)--(10.283,0.796);
  \draw[gp path] (10.283,8.381)--(10.283,8.201);
  \node[gp node center] at (10.283,0.308) {$2.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,0.616)--(10.283,0.616)--(10.283,8.381)--cycle;
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (1.012,8.381) rectangle (10.283,0.616);
    \def\gprawrgbimagedata{%
      9309ddffff00000000d04c00}%
    \gprawimage{rgb}{1.012}{0.616}{2}{2}{9.271}{7.765}{\gprawrgbimagedata}{}
  \end{scope}
  \draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,0.616)--(10.283,0.616)--(10.283,8.381)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.011,0.000,0.001}} (10.515,0.616)--(10.978,0.616)--(10.978,0.677)--(10.515,0.677)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.089,0.000,0.049}} (10.515,0.676)--(10.978,0.676)--(10.978,0.738)--(10.515,0.738)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.125,0.000,0.099}} (10.515,0.737)--(10.978,0.737)--(10.978,0.798)--(10.515,0.798)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.153,0.000,0.147}} (10.515,0.797)--(10.978,0.797)--(10.978,0.859)--(10.515,0.859)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.177,0.000,0.195}} (10.515,0.858)--(10.978,0.858)--(10.978,0.920)--(10.515,0.920)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.198,0.000,0.244}} (10.515,0.919)--(10.978,0.919)--(10.978,0.980)--(10.515,0.980)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.217,0.000,0.290}} (10.515,0.979)--(10.978,0.979)--(10.978,1.041)--(10.515,1.041)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.234,0.000,0.337}} (10.515,1.040)--(10.978,1.040)--(10.978,1.102)--(10.515,1.102)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.250,0.000,0.383}} (10.515,1.101)--(10.978,1.101)--(10.978,1.162)--(10.515,1.162)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.265,0.000,0.428}} (10.515,1.161)--(10.978,1.161)--(10.978,1.223)--(10.515,1.223)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.280,0.000,0.472}} (10.515,1.222)--(10.978,1.222)--(10.978,1.284)--(10.515,1.284)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.293,0.001,0.515}} (10.515,1.283)--(10.978,1.283)--(10.978,1.344)--(10.515,1.344)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.306,0.001,0.556}} (10.515,1.343)--(10.978,1.343)--(10.978,1.405)--(10.515,1.405)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.319,0.001,0.596}} (10.515,1.404)--(10.978,1.404)--(10.978,1.466)--(10.515,1.466)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.331,0.001,0.635}} (10.515,1.465)--(10.978,1.465)--(10.978,1.526)--(10.515,1.526)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.342,0.002,0.672}} (10.515,1.525)--(10.978,1.525)--(10.978,1.587)--(10.515,1.587)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.354,0.002,0.707}} (10.515,1.586)--(10.978,1.586)--(10.978,1.648)--(10.515,1.648)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.365,0.002,0.741}} (10.515,1.647)--(10.978,1.647)--(10.978,1.708)--(10.515,1.708)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.375,0.003,0.773}} (10.515,1.707)--(10.978,1.707)--(10.978,1.769)--(10.515,1.769)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.385,0.003,0.803}} (10.515,1.768)--(10.978,1.768)--(10.978,1.830)--(10.515,1.830)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.395,0.004,0.832}} (10.515,1.829)--(10.978,1.829)--(10.978,1.890)--(10.515,1.890)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.405,0.004,0.858}} (10.515,1.889)--(10.978,1.889)--(10.978,1.951)--(10.515,1.951)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.415,0.005,0.882}} (10.515,1.950)--(10.978,1.950)--(10.978,2.012)--(10.515,2.012)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.424,0.006,0.904}} (10.515,2.011)--(10.978,2.011)--(10.978,2.072)--(10.515,2.072)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.433,0.007,0.924}} (10.515,2.071)--(10.978,2.071)--(10.978,2.133)--(10.515,2.133)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.442,0.007,0.942}} (10.515,2.132)--(10.978,2.132)--(10.978,2.194)--(10.515,2.194)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.451,0.008,0.957}} (10.515,2.193)--(10.978,2.193)--(10.978,2.254)--(10.515,2.254)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.459,0.009,0.970}} (10.515,2.253)--(10.978,2.253)--(10.978,2.315)--(10.515,2.315)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.468,0.010,0.981}} (10.515,2.314)--(10.978,2.314)--(10.978,2.376)--(10.515,2.376)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.476,0.012,0.989}} (10.515,2.375)--(10.978,2.375)--(10.978,2.436)--(10.515,2.436)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.484,0.013,0.995}} (10.515,2.435)--(10.978,2.435)--(10.978,2.497)--(10.515,2.497)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.492,0.014,0.999}} (10.515,2.496)--(10.978,2.496)--(10.978,2.558)--(10.515,2.558)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.500,0.016,1.000}} (10.515,2.557)--(10.978,2.557)--(10.978,2.618)--(10.515,2.618)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.508,0.017,0.999}} (10.515,2.617)--(10.978,2.617)--(10.978,2.679)--(10.515,2.679)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.515,0.019,0.995}} (10.515,2.678)--(10.978,2.678)--(10.978,2.740)--(10.515,2.740)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.523,0.020,0.989}} (10.515,2.739)--(10.978,2.739)--(10.978,2.800)--(10.515,2.800)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.530,0.022,0.981}} (10.515,2.799)--(10.978,2.799)--(10.978,2.861)--(10.515,2.861)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.538,0.024,0.970}} (10.515,2.860)--(10.978,2.860)--(10.978,2.922)--(10.515,2.922)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.545,0.026,0.957}} (10.515,2.921)--(10.978,2.921)--(10.978,2.982)--(10.515,2.982)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.552,0.028,0.942}} (10.515,2.981)--(10.978,2.981)--(10.978,3.043)--(10.515,3.043)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.559,0.031,0.924}} (10.515,3.042)--(10.978,3.042)--(10.978,3.104)--(10.515,3.104)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.566,0.033,0.904}} (10.515,3.103)--(10.978,3.103)--(10.978,3.164)--(10.515,3.164)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.573,0.035,0.882}} (10.515,3.163)--(10.978,3.163)--(10.978,3.225)--(10.515,3.225)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.580,0.038,0.858}} (10.515,3.224)--(10.978,3.224)--(10.978,3.286)--(10.515,3.286)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.586,0.041,0.831}} (10.515,3.285)--(10.978,3.285)--(10.978,3.346)--(10.515,3.346)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.593,0.043,0.803}} (10.515,3.345)--(10.978,3.345)--(10.978,3.407)--(10.515,3.407)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.600,0.046,0.773}} (10.515,3.406)--(10.978,3.406)--(10.978,3.468)--(10.515,3.468)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.606,0.050,0.741}} (10.515,3.467)--(10.978,3.467)--(10.978,3.528)--(10.515,3.528)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.612,0.053,0.707}} (10.515,3.527)--(10.978,3.527)--(10.978,3.589)--(10.515,3.589)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.619,0.056,0.671}} (10.515,3.588)--(10.978,3.588)--(10.978,3.650)--(10.515,3.650)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.625,0.060,0.634}} (10.515,3.649)--(10.978,3.649)--(10.978,3.710)--(10.515,3.710)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.631,0.063,0.596}} (10.515,3.709)--(10.978,3.709)--(10.978,3.771)--(10.515,3.771)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.637,0.067,0.555}} (10.515,3.770)--(10.978,3.770)--(10.978,3.832)--(10.515,3.832)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.644,0.071,0.514}} (10.515,3.831)--(10.978,3.831)--(10.978,3.892)--(10.515,3.892)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.650,0.075,0.471}} (10.515,3.891)--(10.978,3.891)--(10.978,3.953)--(10.515,3.953)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.656,0.079,0.427}} (10.515,3.952)--(10.978,3.952)--(10.978,4.014)--(10.515,4.014)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.662,0.084,0.382}} (10.515,4.013)--(10.978,4.013)--(10.978,4.074)--(10.515,4.074)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.667,0.088,0.337}} (10.515,4.073)--(10.978,4.073)--(10.978,4.135)--(10.515,4.135)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.673,0.093,0.290}} (10.515,4.134)--(10.978,4.134)--(10.978,4.196)--(10.515,4.196)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.679,0.098,0.242}} (10.515,4.195)--(10.978,4.195)--(10.978,4.256)--(10.515,4.256)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.685,0.103,0.195}} (10.515,4.255)--(10.978,4.255)--(10.978,4.317)--(10.515,4.317)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.690,0.108,0.146}} (10.515,4.316)--(10.978,4.316)--(10.978,4.378)--(10.515,4.378)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.696,0.114,0.097}} (10.515,4.377)--(10.978,4.377)--(10.978,4.438)--(10.515,4.438)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.702,0.119,0.049}} (10.515,4.437)--(10.978,4.437)--(10.978,4.499)--(10.515,4.499)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.707,0.125,0.000}} (10.515,4.498)--(10.978,4.498)--(10.978,4.560)--(10.515,4.560)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.713,0.131,0.000}} (10.515,4.559)--(10.978,4.559)--(10.978,4.620)--(10.515,4.620)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.718,0.137,0.000}} (10.515,4.619)--(10.978,4.619)--(10.978,4.681)--(10.515,4.681)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.724,0.143,0.000}} (10.515,4.680)--(10.978,4.680)--(10.978,4.742)--(10.515,4.742)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.729,0.150,0.000}} (10.515,4.741)--(10.978,4.741)--(10.978,4.802)--(10.515,4.802)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.734,0.157,0.000}} (10.515,4.801)--(10.978,4.801)--(10.978,4.863)--(10.515,4.863)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.740,0.164,0.000}} (10.515,4.862)--(10.978,4.862)--(10.978,4.924)--(10.515,4.924)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.745,0.171,0.000}} (10.515,4.923)--(10.978,4.923)--(10.978,4.984)--(10.515,4.984)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.750,0.178,0.000}} (10.515,4.983)--(10.978,4.983)--(10.978,5.045)--(10.515,5.045)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.755,0.186,0.000}} (10.515,5.044)--(10.978,5.044)--(10.978,5.106)--(10.515,5.106)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.760,0.193,0.000}} (10.515,5.105)--(10.978,5.105)--(10.978,5.166)--(10.515,5.166)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.765,0.201,0.000}} (10.515,5.165)--(10.978,5.165)--(10.978,5.227)--(10.515,5.227)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.771,0.209,0.000}} (10.515,5.226)--(10.978,5.226)--(10.978,5.288)--(10.515,5.288)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.776,0.218,0.000}} (10.515,5.287)--(10.978,5.287)--(10.978,5.348)--(10.515,5.348)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.781,0.226,0.000}} (10.515,5.347)--(10.978,5.347)--(10.978,5.409)--(10.515,5.409)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.786,0.235,0.000}} (10.515,5.408)--(10.978,5.408)--(10.978,5.470)--(10.515,5.470)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.791,0.244,0.000}} (10.515,5.469)--(10.978,5.469)--(10.978,5.530)--(10.515,5.530)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.796,0.253,0.000}} (10.515,5.529)--(10.978,5.529)--(10.978,5.591)--(10.515,5.591)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.800,0.263,0.000}} (10.515,5.590)--(10.978,5.590)--(10.978,5.652)--(10.515,5.652)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.805,0.273,0.000}} (10.515,5.651)--(10.978,5.651)--(10.978,5.712)--(10.515,5.712)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.810,0.283,0.000}} (10.515,5.711)--(10.978,5.711)--(10.978,5.773)--(10.515,5.773)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.815,0.293,0.000}} (10.515,5.772)--(10.978,5.772)--(10.978,5.834)--(10.515,5.834)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.820,0.303,0.000}} (10.515,5.833)--(10.978,5.833)--(10.978,5.894)--(10.515,5.894)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.824,0.314,0.000}} (10.515,5.893)--(10.978,5.893)--(10.978,5.955)--(10.515,5.955)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.829,0.325,0.000}} (10.515,5.954)--(10.978,5.954)--(10.978,6.016)--(10.515,6.016)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.834,0.336,0.000}} (10.515,6.015)--(10.978,6.015)--(10.978,6.076)--(10.515,6.076)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.839,0.348,0.000}} (10.515,6.075)--(10.978,6.075)--(10.978,6.137)--(10.515,6.137)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.843,0.359,0.000}} (10.515,6.136)--(10.978,6.136)--(10.978,6.198)--(10.515,6.198)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.848,0.371,0.000}} (10.515,6.197)--(10.978,6.197)--(10.978,6.258)--(10.515,6.258)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.852,0.384,0.000}} (10.515,6.257)--(10.978,6.257)--(10.978,6.319)--(10.515,6.319)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.857,0.396,0.000}} (10.515,6.318)--(10.978,6.318)--(10.978,6.380)--(10.515,6.380)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.862,0.409,0.000}} (10.515,6.379)--(10.978,6.379)--(10.978,6.440)--(10.515,6.440)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.866,0.422,0.000}} (10.515,6.439)--(10.978,6.439)--(10.978,6.501)--(10.515,6.501)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.871,0.435,0.000}} (10.515,6.500)--(10.978,6.500)--(10.978,6.562)--(10.515,6.562)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.875,0.449,0.000}} (10.515,6.561)--(10.978,6.561)--(10.978,6.622)--(10.515,6.622)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.879,0.463,0.000}} (10.515,6.621)--(10.978,6.621)--(10.978,6.683)--(10.515,6.683)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.884,0.477,0.000}} (10.515,6.682)--(10.978,6.682)--(10.978,6.744)--(10.515,6.744)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.888,0.492,0.000}} (10.515,6.743)--(10.978,6.743)--(10.978,6.804)--(10.515,6.804)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.893,0.506,0.000}} (10.515,6.803)--(10.978,6.803)--(10.978,6.865)--(10.515,6.865)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.897,0.521,0.000}} (10.515,6.864)--(10.978,6.864)--(10.978,6.926)--(10.515,6.926)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.901,0.537,0.000}} (10.515,6.925)--(10.978,6.925)--(10.978,6.986)--(10.515,6.986)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.906,0.552,0.000}} (10.515,6.985)--(10.978,6.985)--(10.978,7.047)--(10.515,7.047)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.910,0.568,0.000}} (10.515,7.046)--(10.978,7.046)--(10.978,7.108)--(10.515,7.108)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.914,0.584,0.000}} (10.515,7.107)--(10.978,7.107)--(10.978,7.168)--(10.515,7.168)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.919,0.601,0.000}} (10.515,7.167)--(10.978,7.167)--(10.978,7.229)--(10.515,7.229)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.923,0.618,0.000}} (10.515,7.228)--(10.978,7.228)--(10.978,7.290)--(10.515,7.290)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.927,0.635,0.000}} (10.515,7.289)--(10.978,7.289)--(10.978,7.350)--(10.515,7.350)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.931,0.652,0.000}} (10.515,7.349)--(10.978,7.349)--(10.978,7.411)--(10.515,7.411)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.935,0.670,0.000}} (10.515,7.410)--(10.978,7.410)--(10.978,7.472)--(10.515,7.472)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.940,0.688,0.000}} (10.515,7.471)--(10.978,7.471)--(10.978,7.532)--(10.515,7.532)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.944,0.707,0.000}} (10.515,7.531)--(10.978,7.531)--(10.978,7.593)--(10.515,7.593)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.948,0.725,0.000}} (10.515,7.592)--(10.978,7.592)--(10.978,7.654)--(10.515,7.654)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.952,0.745,0.000}} (10.515,7.653)--(10.978,7.653)--(10.978,7.714)--(10.515,7.714)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.956,0.764,0.000}} (10.515,7.713)--(10.978,7.713)--(10.978,7.775)--(10.515,7.775)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.960,0.784,0.000}} (10.515,7.774)--(10.978,7.774)--(10.978,7.836)--(10.515,7.836)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.964,0.804,0.000}} (10.515,7.835)--(10.978,7.835)--(10.978,7.896)--(10.515,7.896)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.968,0.824,0.000}} (10.515,7.895)--(10.978,7.895)--(10.978,7.957)--(10.515,7.957)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.972,0.845,0.000}} (10.515,7.956)--(10.978,7.956)--(10.978,8.018)--(10.515,8.018)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.976,0.866,0.000}} (10.515,8.017)--(10.978,8.017)--(10.978,8.078)--(10.515,8.078)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.980,0.887,0.000}} (10.515,8.077)--(10.978,8.077)--(10.978,8.139)--(10.515,8.139)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.984,0.909,0.000}} (10.515,8.138)--(10.978,8.138)--(10.978,8.200)--(10.515,8.200)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.988,0.932,0.000}} (10.515,8.199)--(10.978,8.199)--(10.978,8.260)--(10.515,8.260)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.992,0.954,0.000}} (10.515,8.259)--(10.978,8.259)--(10.978,8.321)--(10.515,8.321)--cycle;
  \gpfill{rgb color={0.996,0.977,0.000}} (10.515,8.320)--(10.978,8.320)--(10.978,8.381)--(10.515,8.381)--cycle;
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,0.616)--(10.978,0.616)--(10.978,8.381)--(10.515,8.381)--cycle;
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,0.616)--(10.798,0.616);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,0.616) {$1$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,0.616)--(10.695,0.616);
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,1.910)--(10.798,1.910);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,1.910) {$1.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,1.910)--(10.695,1.910);
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,3.204)--(10.798,3.204);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,3.204) {$2$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,3.204)--(10.695,3.204);
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,4.498)--(10.798,4.498);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,4.498) {$2.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,4.498)--(10.695,4.498);
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,5.792)--(10.798,5.792);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,5.792) {$3$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,5.792)--(10.695,5.792);
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,7.086)--(10.798,7.086);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,7.086) {$3.5$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,7.086)--(10.695,7.086);
  \draw[gp path] (10.978,8.381)--(10.798,8.381);
  \node[gp node left] at (11.162,8.381) {$4$};
  \draw[gp path] (10.515,8.381)--(10.695,8.381);
  %% coordinates of the plot area
  \gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{1.012cm}{0.616cm}}{\pgfpoint{10.283cm}{8.381cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

LuaLaTeX output:

[image: proper plot]